# PHP deletes temp files when trying to upload

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload a file to server but file is being deleted before I called move_uploaded_file.

I know that because I print those lines to error_log and the first returns 1 and second returns 0.

```
<?php
$target_dir = 'uploads/';
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
error_log(print_r($_FILES));
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
error_log(print_r($_FILES));

    if($check !== false) {
        echo 'File is an image - ' . $check['mime'] . '.';
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo 'File is not an image.';
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo 'Sorry, file already exists.';
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] > 500000) {
    echo 'Sorry, your file is too large.';
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != 'jpg' && $imageFileType != 'png' && $imageFileType != 'jpeg'
&& $imageFileType != 'gif' ) {
    echo 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.';
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
error_log(print_r($uploadOk,true));
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo 'Sorry, your file was not uploaded.';
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {  
        echo 'The file '. basename( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']). ' has been uploaded.';
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.';
    }
}
?>
```

---

```
function uploadFile(){
    var file = $('#fileToUpload')[0].files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("fileToUpload", file);
    console.log(formdata);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "upload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

---

```
<form>
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="button" value="Upload Image" onclick="uploadFile()" >
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "//returns 1" and "//returns 0"? A call to `error_log()` returns a boolean, not `0` or `1`. But even if, what does that say about some temporary file?

Comment: But it must returns the same value correct? Why it's different? The server send the file first to temp directory right? Then I have to call move_uploaded_file right?

Comment: An uploaded file is saved in some temporary location, that is correct. And you _have to_ move such final to a final destination _within the same script run_, also correct. I cannot say why a call to `error_log()` should behave different, but that is fishy anyway, since as said: it does not return a number.

Comment: Let's ask the other way 'round: why do you think the temporary saved file has vanished? What happens if you try to use it? And could you please post the actual script you use without those disruptions? I suspect we are not looking at a php issue here, but at how you understand the logic required.

Comment: I only used error_log to debug because I didn't understand what's happening. The $target_file is correct. The problem is when I'm trying to check if image file is really an image the $check will be 0 because $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] is also 0.

Comment: Are you really sure that both attempts are done within the same script run? And do you check the image size _before_ moving the file?

Comment: I've added the script and the html form too

Comment: This raises even more questions... `$_POST['submit']` will _never_ be set when uploading a file using the code you have posted...

Comment: I've remove the if statement that contains $_POST['submit'] and it still not working

Comment: And "still not working" means what? Remember that we cannot look over your shoulder. You initial statement was that php removes files. That is all the information we have.

Comment: Another thing: you should _never_ use the file name as specified by the client in file operations on the server side. You cannot trust any data the client provides. You do not know what it contains. Just imagine what happens if it contains something as `../../../../etc/passwd` for example, I guess you get the idea... Use an internal name, typically constructed by combining a user name and a timestamp or something. If you really need the original file name then store it inside a database. But do _not_ use it in file operations.